# Calculate totals for selected checkboxes in userform using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm Creating an userform with multiple checkboxes, where I want to Calculate/totals for the selected checkboxes and to be displayed in the Userform itself.

[Actual Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aBWI.png)

Code for **Estimate** button:

```
Private Sub preflight_calculate_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Preflight")
With ws
LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
   For j = 0 To us_mp0.Selected - 1
       lbValue = us_mp0.Selected(j)

       If .Cells(i, "A").Value = lbValue Or _
          .Cells(i, "A").Value = Val(lbValue) Then
           preflight_resource = Val(preflight_resource) + Val(.Cells(i, "G").Value)
           preflight_time = Val(preflight_time) + Val(.Cells(i, "I").Value)
       End If
   Next
 Next
 End With
 End Sub
```

**In Userform you can see P0, P1, P2, so those only will have values in the excel sheet and from there only I need to calculate totals for selected checkboxes**

[Excel Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tWr3.png)

Any thought? Thanks in Advance

Comment: you should add a screenshot of your sheet

Comment: @DisplayName Added sheet screenshot

Comment: How are the check boxes named? Do they have group names? How are they linked to the worksheet? Where are the values to sum up? Why doesn't your UserForm have a single group of check boxes and a drop-down from which to select the Locale?

Comment: "Any thought?" - plenty of thoughts - is there a specific problem or issue you would like addressed?

Comment: @Variatus
Ans for Que 1: checkboxes are named as "us_mp0" for US-> Mobile-> P0 and "us_dp0" for US-> Desktop-> P0
Ans for Que 2: No group names
Ans for Que 3: No they haven't linked to the worksheet
Ans for Que 4: They sum up and to be displayed in the two text boxes presented in the Userform
Ans for Que 5: Userform doesn't have single group checkbox because I may have to select all the locales at some time. So that is the reason

Comment: @AJD I want to total the only selected checkboxes which represents each cells in the sheet I have attached

Comment: "preflight_resource" and "preflight_time" is the name for two resulting textboxes

Answer (score 0):

best way is to:

- rename all your chekboxes to reflect task and mobile/desktop values (e.g. "US-P0|Mobile", ""US-P2|Mobile", ...")
- loop through all controls (e.g.: `For Each ctl In Me.Controls`)
- select "chekboxes" type ones (e.g. `If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then`)
- split its name into wanted strings (e.g.: `task = Split(taskString, "|")(0)`, `mobileOrDesktopOffset = IIf(Split(taskString, "|")(1) = "Mobile", 0, 1)`)
- finally do proper sums

You can try this code which doesn't need to rename checkboxes as above said, (but you really shoud do that..):

```
Private Sub preflight_calculate_Click()
    Dim preflight_resource As Double, preflight_time As Double

    Dim taskRng As Range
    Dim taskString As Variant
    Dim task As String, mobileOrDesktopOffset As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Preflight")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

            preflight_resource = Val(Me.preflight_resource)
            preflight_time = Val(Me.preflight_time)
            For Each taskString In GetTasks
                task = Split(taskString, "|")(0)
                mobileOrDesktopOffset = IIf(Split(taskString, "|")(1) = "Mobile", 0, 1)
                Set taskRng = .Find(what:=task, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                preflight_resource = preflight_resource + taskRng.Offset(, 5 + mobileOrDesktopOffset).Value
                preflight_time = preflight_time + taskRng.Offset(, 7 + mobileOrDesktopOffset).Value
            Next
        End With
    End With

    With Me
        .preflight_resource.Text = preflight_resource
        .preflight_time.Text = preflight_time
    End With
End Sub


Function GetTasks() As Variant
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim mobileLeft As Long, desktopLeft As Long

    With Me
        For Each ctl In .Controls
            If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
                If ctl.Value Then
                    GetTasks = GetTasks & " " & ctl.Parent.Caption & "-" & ctl.Caption & "|" & GetMobileOrDesktop(ctl)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    GetTasks = Split(Trim(GetTasks))
End Function


Function GetMobileOrDesktop(ctl As Control) As String
    Dim ctl1 As Control
    For Each ctl1 In ctl.Parent.Controls
        If ctl1.Caption = "Mobile" Then
            If ctl1.left = ctl.left Then
                GetMobileOrDesktop = "Mobile"
            Else
                GetMobileOrDesktop = "Desktop"
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: So, How can it calculate Mobile Resource count and Desktop Resource count if both are selected?

Comment: Similarly how can it calculate if Time for MA and Time for Desktop if both are selected?

Comment: For Example: If I select US Desktop P1, It should only calculate cell: G3 and If US Mobile P1 is also selected then it should calculate F3 along with G3

Comment: Getting Type mismatch error in ` preflight_resource = preflight_resource + cell.Offset(, 6).Value`

Comment: See edited answer. As for mismatch error you can try resuming that `Val()` function to enclose `cell.Offset(, 6).Value` and see what happens

Comment: When I ran first Sub: I get the error: Object variable not set on 

preflight_resource = preflight_resource + taskRng.Offset(, 5 + mobileOrDesktopOffset).Value

Comment: Why should you have two sub with the same name?

Comment: As for the object variabke not set it seems like it didn’t find current task in column A of your sheet: double chek task value and its occurrence in column A

Comment: your code really helps me to move further in the entire process, I would really appreciate if you could influence me in this code for better picture. 
you can ping me in tmaniacker@gmail.com, and I would like to share the excel with you. Glad you did this far

Comment: as for the double sub it was a copy/paste mistake of mine. I edited code to leave the valid `preflight_calculate_Click` only

Comment: _"do I have to rename the checkboxes to run the above your code? "_: why are you asking that? Wasn't my comment just before the code _"doesn't need to rename checkboxes as above said"_ clear enough?

Comment: _"Yes I double checked it is there only in column A "_: be sure you're searching the right text (spaces matters and cases may) in the right column of the right sheet in the right workbook

Comment: If I dont have to rename the checkboxes. then why we are splitting using the follwing code? "mobileOrDesktopOffset = IIf(Split(taskString, "|")(1) = "Mobile", 0, 1)"

Comment: And can you explain me functionality of this function code:
Function GetTasks() As Variant

Comment: I’m not sharing anything. Stick to the code and say what’s not working in proper detail

Comment: The code now only add Mobile column.. if the case I select mobile and desktop P0, P1& P2 it does not adds the total value

Answer (score 0):

You may use class with something like below, the rest may left for your self-learning:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents Chk As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub Chk_Change()
    If Chk Then
        .ChkCount = .ChkCount + 1
    Else
        .ChkCount = .ChkCount - 1
    End If
End Sub
```