# Unable to add cell values based on the Checkbox selection from Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a Userform

What I am trying to achieve: while running my Userform with multiple selection checkboxes.

1. Collect all checked checkboxes captions along with its parent frame name
2. Filtering database on its first column with those collected strings
3. Loop through filtered cells and make the wanted sums
4. The selection can contain each row with different columns (Based on checkbox selection)

Refer Example below for better understanding

[Excel sheet snapshot which contains data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyNIw.png)

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbvyV.png)

Coded for **Estimate button**

```
Private Sub preflight_calculate_Click()
Dim preflight_resource As Double, preflight_time As Double

preflight_resource = Val(Me.preflight_resource)
preflight_time = Val(Me.preflight_time)
Dim cell As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Preflight")
    With .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, Criteria1:=GetCheckedCaptions, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            preflight_resource = Val(preflight_resource) + cell.Offset(, 6).Value
            preflight_time = Val(preflight_time) + cell.Offset(, 8).Value
        Next
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

With Me
    .preflight_resource.Text = preflight_resource
    .preflight_time.Text = preflight_time
End With
End Sub

Function GetCheckedCaptions() As Variant
Dim ctl As Control
With Me
    For Each ctl In .Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ctl.Value Then
                GetCheckedCaptions = GetCheckedCaptions & " " & ctl.Parent.Caption & "-" & ctl.Caption
            End If
        End If
    Next
End With
GetCheckedCaptions = Split(Trim(GetCheckedCaptions))
End Function
```

**Expected result: 
For Example:**

If I select the checkbox as follows US -> Mobile -> P0 and US -> Desktop -> P1

**Output should be:**

Textboxes below:

Resource Utilized: (F2 + G3) -> (0.73 + 0.62) -> **1.35** (Inside text box)

Time in Hours: (H2 + I3) -> (5.87 + 4.95) -> **10.82** (Inside text box)

How to achieve this?

My Excel file link: ("Preflight" is the sheet name where the data is present) Userform will be visible from "Estimation Form" sheet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K2LdVuJXNZoavrkcQgslY20c4R9nlRfo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Isn’t this the same topic as [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966060/calculate-totals-for-selected-checkboxes-in-userform-using-excel-vba]?

Comment: @DisplayName ya I saw it but that didn't solved my problem here !

Comment: If the case I select mobile and desktop P0, P1& P2 it does not adds the total value and display in my text boxes

Comment: Duplicate at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966060/calculate-totals-for-selected-checkboxes-in-userform-using-excel-vba]